# Re-enabling the console once the kernel is up, if silent mode was set in Uboot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

I have enabled the silent mode by setting the U-boot env variable "silent".

```
Uboot-> setenv silent 1
Uboot-> saveenv
```

Now, I would like to re-enable the console once the kernel is up.

Can anyone please tell me how to do so ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try after rebuilding U-Boot with

```
#define CONFIG_SILENT_U_BOOT_ONLY
```

Some discussion is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/22143253/1821972

Comment: Thanks !! It may help. Unfortunately, I can't modify the U-Boot. I am looking for some solution which can be implemented once Kernel is up. Something like re-enabling console.